# insert multiple value from a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, implode

i have a database with 2 rows named start_time and end_time, wanted to insert values from my dynamic form by using implode() but can't seem to insert the values from the succeeding input fields.

[image]

database

[image]

sign-up.php

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="starttime[]" placeholder="12:00">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="col-md-2"><h5>TO</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endtime[]" placeholder="12:00">
</div>
```

sign-up.php

```
$startTime = implode(",", $_POST['starttime']);
    $endTime = implode(",", $_POST['endtime']);

    if($uname=="")  {
        $error[] = "provide username !";    
    }
    else if($upass=="") {
        $error[] = "provide password !";
    }
    else if(strlen($upass) < 6){
        $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters"; 
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE last_name=:uname");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row['last_name']==$uname) {
                $error[] = "Username already taken !";
            }
            else
            {
                if($user->register($startTime,$endTime)){   
                    $user->redirect('sign-up.php?joined');
                }
            }
        }
```

class.user.php

```
public function register($fName,$mName,$uname,$upass,$grdLvl,$subjects,$startTime,$endTime)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name,middle_name,last_name,user_pass,grade_lvl,subjects,start_time,end_time) 
                                                       VALUES(:fName,:mName,:uname,:upass,:grdLvl,:subjects,:startTime,:endTime)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":fName", $fName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":mName", $mName);                                  
            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);      
            $stmt->bindparam(":grdLvl", $grdLvl);   
            $stmt->bindparam(":subjects", $subjects);   
            $stmt->bindparam(":startTime", $startTime); 
            $stmt->bindparam(":endTime", $endTime);                               

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }
```

local.js

```
$("#add-entry").click(function(e){
      console.log("called");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#items").append('<div class="row">'
            +'<div class="col-xs-4">'
            +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="starttime[]" placeholder="12:00">'
            +'</div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="col-md-2"><h5>TO</h5></div></div>'
            +'<div class="col-xs-4">'
            +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="endtime[]" placeholder="12:00"></div>'
            +'<div class="col-xs-1"><input type="button" value="delete" id="delete-entry"></div></div>');
    });
```

Comment: Do your succeeding text inputs have the names ```starttime[]``` and ```endtime[]```? If so then ```$_POST['starttime']``` should be an array.

Comment: yes it does but its on a javasript file

Comment: I can't see why that would not work. Are you sure you are appending to the form element? Can you show us and example of what $_POST['starttime'] is?

Answer (score 0):

If you implode your start time field, you get an string with all start times concatenated - which doesn't seem what you want.

Instead, you should iterate over the array of your start and end times and handle each entry on their own

```
for ($i = 0; i < count($_POST['starttime']); $i++) {
    $starttime = $_POST['starttime'];
    $endtime = $_POST['endtime'];

    // do something usefull and register user
}
```

Comment: i want to insert all values of start time in one row like this (12:20,3:00,5:30) i think implode is right, i just dont know how to include the values from the succeeding text fields